# JavaScript help in animation

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, fadein, fadeout

"I want disable fade-in and fade-out animation after one time its apply on whole web page"

I need a pure JavaScript code which disable fade-in and fade-out animation after it apply one time

```
.fade {
   /* transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in;*/
    opacity: 0;   
  }

.fade.visible {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', fade);
function fade()
{
  let animation=document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
  for (let i=0; i<animation.length; i++)
  {
    let windowheight=window.innerHeight;
    let top=animation[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (top < windowheight)
    {
    animation[i].classList.add('visible');
    }
    else
    {
     animation[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a count variable. When the function that involves the fade-in and fade-out is triggered, add to the count variable. After it is increased, make it so these changes do not occur any more.

```
let count = 0; 
count++;
```

If you want to have more code in the answer, post some more from your specific example.

Comment: can you write complete code i dont understand plz

Comment: @engr.hasnat Can you include your code so I can build off of it?

Comment: window.addEventListener('scroll', fade);
function fade()
{
  let animation=document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
  for (let i=0; i<animation.length; i++)
  {
    let windowheight=window.innerHeight;
    let top=animation[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (top < windowheight)
    {
    animation[i].classList.add('visible');
    }
    else
    {
     animation[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }   
 }
}

Comment: Can you add this code into the actual post in a code block? This will make it much easier to see and edit.

Comment: yeah I add code on my question

Comment: I hate to keep asking for things but it would really help to see the HTML/CSS as well. Is there any chance you can add those?

Comment: css of fade-in and fade-out also added in question, in html only fade class is used

Comment: Ok but it would be helpful to actually have the HTML to see the effect the code is having on it.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a count variable. If you want the animation to occur exactly once, then this should work as the count is increased by one after the animation occurs, making sure it will not happen again.

```js
let count = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', fade);

function fade()
{
  if (count < 1)
  {
    let animation=document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
    for (let i=0; i<animation.length; i++)
    {
      let windowheight=window.innerHeight;
      let top=animation[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      if (top < windowheight)
      {
      animation[i].classList.add('visible');
      }
      else
      {
      animation[i].classList.remove('visible');
      }    
     }
   }
   else
   {
     return;
   }
   count++;
}
```